# How can I combine three spheres properly

Tags: blender

I'm trying to combine three spheres in a way that I can be able to modify the crease, like making the crease sharper or more round. I've tried using boolean but it doesn't come out quite right when I use subdivision modifier or when I use smooth shade.

[three spheres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUfKy.png)

[three spheres combined using boolean and smooth shade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2krwj.png)

Comment: [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Question belongs to another network